# Run-Time Error '3075' Syntax Error in date in query expression ' activitydate between ## and ## and clientid=''

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Me.subfrmActivity.Form.RecordSource = "select * from tblactivity " & _
" where activitydate between #" & numWeek.Column(1) & "# and #" & DateAdd("d", 6,   numWeek.Column(1)) & "#" & _
" and clientid='" & cboClientid & "'" & _
" order by activitydate,keysort"
```

Trying to get rid of the Syntax error be at it for a couple errors hoping I can get some other eyes on it

Comment: Just prints out Null

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```vb
Me.subfrmActivity.Form.RecordSource = "select * from tblactivity " & _
" where activitydate between #" & numWeek.Column(1) & "# and DateAdd('d', 6, " &  numWeek.Column(1)) & ")" & _
" and clientid='" & cboClientid & "'" & _
" order by activitydate,keysort"
```

Comment: Nope get a Complie Error: Syntax error. With that change

Comment: Try againg, now with single-quotes.